# Dockerized React on Heroku: Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, heroku, deployment

When I am trying to deploy my dockerized React application to Heroku, I just get the following error:

```
Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
```

I tried multiple options, but nothing worked.
Every time I get the error above or the build crashes.

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -yq curl && \
  curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash - && \
  apt-get install -y nodejs

EXPOSE 8080

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app/

RUN npm install && npm run build
```

**heroku.yml**

```
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile
run:
  web: HOST=0.0.0.0 npm start -- --port 8080
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: path.join(__dirname, "src", "index.js"),
  output: {
    path:path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react']
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    'extensions': ['.js', '.tsx', '.ts'],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.join(__dirname, "public", "index.html"),
    }),
  ],
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode=production",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.9",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.11",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.16.7",
    "@tsconfig/node14": "^1.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.25",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.8",
    "ts-node": "^10.7.0",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3",
    "webpack": "^5.72.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.8.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.x"
  }
}
```

**PS:** Until now, I am an absolutely noob at configure node/react projects.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use a specific port in heroku. Heroku automatically binds its preferred port to your web process.

Try to set the port with the environment variable `$PORT`. Or you can also hardcode heroku's default port. That would be the same.

```
HOST=0.0.0.0 npm start -- --port $PORT

//or try this
HOST=0.0.0.0 npm start -- --port 5000
//heroku's default port maybe 3000 or 5000.
//I'm not sure. Try both
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
To be more specific:
I added a const in my `webpack.config.js` and read the PORT from Heroku itself (also set the value as config var).

`const PORT = process.env.PORT`